# How to center a list of iframes

Tags: html, css, iframe, media-queries, center

I'm trying to make media queries and am running into a problem with my YouTube videos that I have embedded. At 100% resolution, there are three videos horizontally next to each other with three videos below them too (6 vids in total), and they're centered and look great. However, when I adjust the zoom to like 170%, the videos all have their own lines and proceed to align to the left. When this happens, I want the vids to be centered instead. How can I fix this?

```
<div class="backgroundcolor">
        <h1>High-lights</h1>
        <hr size="2" color="#987b74">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/HQQ3LfzPrEI" 
                title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                </iframe>
            </li>
            <li>
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/zNUe4U8ps5k" 
                title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                </iframe>
            </li>
            <li>
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Sh7yxSijuxI" 
                title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                </iframe>
            </li>
            
                <li>
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PGgvM_9pZok" 
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/S_M8JgzfdW4" 
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Pk0GZE-3EqQ" 
                    title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; 
                    encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen>
                    </iframe>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

```
.backgroundcolor{ /* To get that cream color background!*/
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.backgroundcolor h1, .backgroundcolor hr{
    margin-bottom: 90px;
}

main{
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.backgroundcolor ul li{ /* Doesn't work :( */
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}



@media screen and (max-width: 640px)
{
    body, html{
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding: 0.8em 0;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    
    .col-25, .col-75, input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  
  .tabs{
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  h2{font-size: 100%;} 
  
  .title{ font-size: 25%;}
  
   .container {
   height: 180px;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
 }
    
  
}



@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    
    
.container nav{
    width: 95%;
    height: 76px;
}   
.container nav ul li {font-size: 25px; width: fit-content; height: fit-content;}
 .container nav ul li ul.sub-nav li{
     font-size: 20px; 
     
 }
 .container nav ul li:hover ul.sub-nav{ /* Drop down menu visibility */
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-right: 40px;
}
 main h2{
    padding-right: 2em;
    padding-left: 2em;
}

}
```

Comment: The zoom isn't important. Instead of that shrink/minimize your browser window sideways for a mobile view. Stay at normal 100% zoom. If you have 3 columns acting normally the Youtube code should just fit right in.

Comment: @CuteCodeRob oh! that's so helpful thank you! when i did that, it still was not centered :(

Comment: All good, all websites do get built in the end with a bit of teeth grinding and sweating. The Youtube code is saying a defined `height` and `width`. See if you can just get that to 100% width (100% of the column it is in).